# How To Limit The Number of Zeros (0) In A String In GUI Used In JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am making a swing app and I have a main class and other classes in the same package. I want to assign JLabel present in another class a string value through another class and when i assign the value it worked fine but i can't limit the number of zeros printing in JLabel Its giving me a lot of errors mainly these.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source).
```

```
view.sub1gpa = new JLabel(String.format("%.2f", fsub1gpa));
view.sub1gpa.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
view.sub1gpa.setFont(f2);
view.sub1gpa.setLocation(200, 340);
view.sub1gpa.setSize(500, 30);
view.resframe.add(view.sub1gpa);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception stacktrace:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
```

is telling you that your `fsub1gpa` variable is holding a String and not a floating point number. You either should use it as a String, or convert it to a double by parsing it with Double, and then format the double value returned.

Better still -- use the original numeric data and don't try to convert it first into a String. Understand that the `String.format(...)` method will do the conversion of number to String for you, but will do it better than your previous raw conversion.

Note also that you probably don't want to add a new JLabel to do what you're doing but rather to simply set the text of a JLabel that's already present in the GUI. For more details on this, please post more details about your own code and program.

Comment: how to format a double value and then convert that formatted double value as a string because JLabel constructor only accept string values.

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman: see edit to answer. You're not yet fully understanding what `String.format(...)` does.

Comment: that is why i am here to understand what is wrong with my code as i am a beginner.

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman: and that's why I'm telling you this, so you'll understand. Understand that I'm not criticizing but rather informing. But the most important understanding that you should gain out of all of this is to read the error messages with a critical eye, since if you look at it closely, you'll see that it tells you fully what your problem is. Keep this in mind for your future problems, and you'll be way ahead.

Comment: Thanks A Lot Bro For your help let me try.

Comment: as you said to not add a new JLabel and simply set the text using setText() method i did this but it gives errors can you tell my why???

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman: It's hard to say based on the limited information that you've presented so far: we don't know exactly what you've done, we have no idea what errors you may be seeing, we have no idea about what your current program structure or code looks like. When asking questions on this site, always try to put yourself in our shoes and ask yourself what total strangers might need in order to understand your problem and your code. Then please edit your question accordingly or ask a new question since it appears to be a new problem. Also look critically at all error messages and try to solve.

Comment: Sorry i am a new member i'll remember all your words for future Thanks for your kind advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to format a String as a double. If the String contains a double before that use Double.parseDouble. Otherwise it will not work.

You can use something like this

```
public Testing (String testing){
        Double one=Double.parseDouble(testing);
        //or you can use

        // where this will format your floating point as you need
        DecimalFormat form=new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        System.out.println(form.format(one));
    }
```

Please notice the form inside the "DecimalFormat" is just an example to get more information on it read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Or the most correct way as mentioned by Hovercraft Full Of Eels , is to understand how String.format works, example:

```
public Testing (Double testing){
        System.out.println(String.format("% 2f", testing));
    }
```

Comment: That String fsub1gpa was previously a double then i converted it to String to use it in JLabel as JLabel constructor only accept String Values.

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman: then you did so in error. Understand that `String.format(...)` will do just that, convert the double to a String, but it will do it better.

Comment: After the constructor accept the String you can format it as a Double or change the parameter of constructor to Double/Float

Comment: can you please provide the code on how to do that it will help a lot thanks.

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman: you've already got the code you need in your own post. Don't parse with `Double.parseDouble(...)` but rather simply use the original double value that you obtained, and don't first change it into a String.

Comment: Thanks A Lot @vsarunov actually String.format() and Double.toString perform the same function i didn't knew it before this was all i wanted to know.